# Mutually dependent Properties

Tags: javafx, properties

I have two fields in my interface representing the minimum and maximum values of a range. These fields are bound to two IntegerProperty's.
If the minimum property is greater than the maximum property, the maximum should be set to the minimum and vice versa. I've archived this using two ChangeListener.

```
IntegerProperty positionFrom = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
IntegerProperty positionTo = new SimpleIntegerProperty(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

positionFrom.addListener((e, oldPosition, newPosition) -> {
  if (newPosition.intValue() > positionTo.get()) {
    positionTo.set(newPosition.intValue());
  }
});

positionTo.addListener((e, oldPosition, newPosition) -> {
  if (newPosition.intValue() < positionFrom.get()) {
    positionFrom.set(newPosition.intValue());
  }
});
```

This works but seems overly complicated to me. So I tried other approaches but none of them worked.

---

1st try

```
positionFrom.bind(Bindings.min(positionFrom.get(), positionTo));
positionTo.bind(Bindings.max(positionTo.get(), positionFrom));
```

Gives StackOverflowError because the two properties keep updating one another.

---

2nd try

```
positionTo.bind(Bindings.when(positionTo.lessThan(positionFrom)).then(positionFrom.intValue()).otherwise(positionTo.intValue()));
```

Gives StackOverflowError.

---

Is there a shorter solution that I missed?

Comment: I don't know whether it will fix your problem, but shouldn't the first try use `Bindings.min` for the first statement?

Comment: The nature of the requirements makes using bindings problematic. You cannot set bound properties yet you need to be able to set them—whether directly or indirectly by setting the other. The `ChangeListener`s you're using in the working code is likely the best/simplest solution. If really necessary, take a look at how JavaFX implements bidirectional binding and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @lu.koerfer this was an error in my example here. Fixed. My test code was correctly using min.